# How to set minimal date in Blazor?

Tags: javascript, html, blazor

I am trying to set min date in date block.

Tried already:
`<input type="date" id="datePickerId" min="@Start"/> @code{ public DateTime Start { get; set; } = new DateTime(2019, 11, 17); }`

And:
`datePickerId.min = new Date(2019, 11, 17)`

And:
`datePickerId.min = new Date('2019-11-17T00:00:00');`

And:
`<input type="date" id="datePickerId" min="2019-11-17"/>`

But dates before 2019-11-17 were still clickable. I would really appreciate some help on how to do them unclickable.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this on chrome edge and firefox. They all seemed to work for me. I could not select a date prior.

```
<input type="date" id="datePickerId" min="2019-11-17" />
<input type="date" id="datePickerId" min="@date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" />
@code {
    DateTime date = new DateTime(2019,11,17);
}
```